# How can i find collaborations?

Tags: r, collaboration

Within patent data, I want to find the amount of times a certain company (Toyota in this case) has collaborated with in filing a patent application.
I have four variables:

1. Applicant ID
2. Company_name
3. CPC_Class (the type of technology the company is filing for)
4. Fraction (which basically shows how many companies worked on the same applicant ID)

So, I want to know:
[image]

The applicant ID (636) has to be the same for both companies --> this shows the collaboration.
How would I find all the times Toyota has collaborated with a company on the same Applicant ID, without losing the name of the other company?

I realize this question is really unclear, but I want to throw it out there anyway to see if anyone gets what I mean. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Do you need more details?

```
setDT(df)

sub <- df[applicant_id==636]
number_of_collaborations <- nrow(sub)
```